# не находит класс в java

Tags: java, linux

использую import

```
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
```

компилирую

```
all:
        javac -classpath javax.mail.jar Main.java
```

компилируется без ошибок. но потом когда запускаю

```
java Main
Error: Unable to initialize main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/NoSuchProviderException
```

если убрать эту ошибку, то появиться другая. как исправить? я в java новичок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятору вы сказали, где лежат нужные классы.
JVM тоже надо это сказать:

`java -classpath javax.mail.jar Main`